# Type hints support for subclass of dict

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

How can I implement a subclass of `dict` so it supports type hints like vanilla `dict`?

I want to create a custom dict that does some extra work when modifying item, I implement it by subclassing the built-in `dict` class. After doing some googling I learned that I need to use the generic class from typing to achieve this:

```py
_KT = TypeVar("_KT")
_VT = TypeVar("_VT")

class CustomDict(dict, Mapping[_KT, _VT]):
    """A dict that call callback function after setting or popping item."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.callback = None

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if self.callback:
            self.callback()

    def pop(self, key, *arg):
        super().pop(key, *arg)
        if self.callback:
            self.callback()

    def register_callback(self, callback: Callable[[], None]):
        self.callback = callback
```

For a vanilla `dict` object, type annotation is added like:

```py
my_dict: dict[int, str] = {}
```

Now my custom dict supports type annotation just like the vanilla `dict`:

```py
my_custom_dict: CustomDict[int, str] = CustomDict()
```

But mypy doesn't throw me an error if I add item with incompatible type:

```py
# the key is type str and the value is type int, which is against the annotation
my_custom_dict["3.234"] = 2
```

For a vanilla dict, doing this mypy will give me an error. So which part did I get wrong and how can I implement the subclass along with the annotation correctly? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't actually use your type variables in the definition of `__setitem__`, which means it isn't typechecked. (Your also forgot to return the value of `super().pop(key, *args)`.) Add the type hints:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Mapping, Callable
_KT = TypeVar("_KT")
_VT = TypeVar("_VT")

class CustomDict(dict, Mapping[_KT, _VT]):
    """A dict that call callback function after setting or popping item."""

    callback: Optional[Callable[[], None]]

    def __init__(self):
        self.callback = None

    def __setitem__(self, key: _KT, value: _VT):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if self.callback:
            self.callback()

    def pop(self, key, *arg) -> _VT:
        rv = super().pop(key, *arg)
        if self.callback:
            self.callback()
        return rv

    def register_callback(self, callback: Callable[[], None]):
        self.callback = callback

my_custom_dict: CustomDict[int, str] = CustomDict()

my_custom_dict["3.234"] = 2
```

and you'll get the expected errors:

```
tmp.py:27: error: Invalid index type "str" for "CustomDict[int, str]"; expected type "int"  [index]
tmp.py:27: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", target has type "str")  [assignment]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Note that you don't need to inherit from `Mapping` (or `MutableMapping`, which is what you would inherit from if you want to support `__setitem__`, though inheriting from `dict` as well is sufficient). Just use `dict` generically:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable
_KT = TypeVar("_KT")
_VT = TypeVar("_VT")

class CustomDict(dict[_KT, _VT]):
    ...
```

As pointed out in a comment, consult [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1020) (the repository of Python stub files for built-in and standard-library code) to see the types of the methods you are overriding, either so you can copy them or ensure that your custom type hints are consistent with them.

---

Unrelated, consider using the do-nothing function `lambda: None` as the default callback instead of `None`. Then you can simply call the callback without checking if it exists.

Comment: And just for the sake of completeness, in such endeavors it is always useful to consult the [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1020).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake, but the `pop` method in your code will not call `self.callback()` after `return` statement, so I improved it: `popped_value = super().pop(key, *arg)\n self.callback()\n return popped_value`. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, lazy mistake on my part. I'll update the answer.